# How do I make a mask of diagonal matrix, but starting from the 2nd column?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor, diagonal

So here is what I can get with `torch.eye(3,4)` now

The matrix I get:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Is there any (easy)way to transform it, or make such a mask in this format:

The matrix I want:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Have a look at torch.roll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `torch.diagonal` and specifying the diagonal you want:

```
>>> torch.diag(torch.tensor([1,1,1]), diagonal=1)[:-1]

tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

> - If :attr:`diagonal` = 0, it is the main diagonal.
> - If :attr:`diagonal` > 0, it is above the main diagonal.
> - If :attr:`diagonal` < 0, it is below the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, well actually I just found a solution by concatenate a zero tensor to the top of a `torch.eye(3)`, then transpose it. But this one is probably more elegant. Thx!

Comment: @ashered diag is probably better, but FYI there's also a `torch.roll` operator that can shift everything along a dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [`torch.diagflat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.diagflat), and using a positive `offset` for shifting/moving the diagonal **above the main diagonal**.

```
# diagonal values to fill
In [253]: diagonal_vals = torch.ones(3, dtype=torch.long)  

# desired tensor but ...
In [254]: torch.diagflat(diagonal_vals, offset=1) 
Out[254]: 
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The above operation gives us a square matrix; however, we need a *non-square matrix* of shape `(3,4)`. So, we'll just ignore the last row with simple indexing:

```
# shape (3, 4) with 1's above the main diagonal
In [255]: torch.diagflat(diagonal_vals, offset=1)[:-1] 
Out[255]: 
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```